# Postgresql schema only works when wrapped in quotation marks

Tags: postgresql, schema, postgresql-9.6

I'm seeing an odd behaviour - if I don't wrap my schema name in quotes, the server returns

> [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "."

The query is simply:

```
select count(*) from "authorization".logins
```

Here's what `psql \dn` shows:

```
     List of schemas
     Name      |  Owner
---------------+---------
 authorization | user_login
(1 row)
```

Schema name doesn't contain upper case letters, only English ones. Tried it using **DataGrip** and **Npgsql** (.NET driver for PostgreSQL). 
DataGrip added quotes around schema name, when with others it doesn't do so.

Table and schema was created and applied via [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/)

Comment: Which query produces the error? `select count(*) from "authorization".logins;` or `select count(*) from authorization.logins;`?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ the one without quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`authorization` is a reserved keyword in Postgres, so it needs to be quoted to be used as a (database/schema/table) name. See the list: [Appendix C. SQL Key Words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

And a very popular opinion among Postgres developers - to avoid the complications - is:
**Do not use reserved words as identifiers**.

Comment: I would even go so far to say: "Never use double quotes for identifiers"